# What do the avifenc min/max quality settings do?

Tags: command-line, images, homebrew

I'm using `avifenc` by joedrago to create AVIF images (for use on the web). I installed it via Homebrew on macOS using:

```
brew install joedrago/repo/avifenc
```

There doesn't seem to be a single quality setting, but instead both min/max values. But I don't really understand what that means, is it supposed to use different quality settings for different parts of the image, like a variable bit-rate encoding for mp3s?

In fact, it doesn't appear to actually do anything. For example these two commands...

```
avifenc --min 30 --max 30 newspaper.jpg newspaper30.avif
avifenc --min 30 --max 50 newspaper.jpg newspaper50.avif
```

...produce identical images (literally identical, as confirmed by `diff`). So it seems like it just uses the minimum and not the max. Curiously though, omitting the max parameter gives this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to finish encoding: Encoding of color planes failed
```

So it seems like the max parameter does nothing, but omitting it causes an error. Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: I just installed it myself, as i want to convert all of my pictures to this new codec. But when i try to convert on my Debian stable, i get a `Speicherzugriffsfehler` (which means segmentation fault)